# how do I search string and see if any letters are there?

Tags: .net

I need to find out if a string contains letters in it. I think I've tried every thing in the world and they haven't worked. I've tried many examples from here (and other places) but they don't work either

I know there are a lot of similar questions. I've read them and they don't work for me, so I'm asking again.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried, show your thinking so far. And when you say they don't work, what error or output are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Regex`

```
Public function containsletter(ByVal text As String) As Boolean
  Dim pattern As String = "[a-z]"
  Dim r As Regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
  Dim m As Match = r.Match(text)
  If m.Success
  Return True;
  Else
  Return False;
  End If
End function
```

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for the code. The one that worked the best for me is the code that reenleedr posted. But I still thank you son much for trying to help, Bryan. A lot of people won't.

Answer (score 3):

```
var s = "123x456";

var hasLetter = s.Any(Char.IsLetter);
```